# How to find Intersections in two singly linked lists

Tags: java, dictionary, intersection, singly-linked-list

I am writing an program in which i have to set up data structure dictionary(singly linked list) with words alphabetically ordered(words that appear in sentence in a text document with document ids). and find which words appear in more than one document so the professor wants us to do an intersection.  I am really confused on how to do the intersection.  I have everything else(Which I believe is correct).  Here is my code(I have added my intersect algorithm, but it is clearly not working and I followed the professors algorithm[she never shows us an example]):

```
public class dictionary 
{
  //variables
  dNode head;
  int size;

  //constructor
  public dictionary() 
  {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  //addFirst method
  public void addFirst(dNode s) 
  {
    s.setNext(head);
    head = s;
    size++;
  }

  public void addLast(dNode s)
  {
    if ( head == null )
    {
      head = s;
    }
    else
    {
      s.setNext(null);
      dNode w = head;
      while ( w.getNext() != null ) 
      { 
        w = w.getNext();
      }
      w.setNext(s);
    }
      size++;
  }

  //toString Method
  public String toString() 
  {
    String w = "";
    dNode s = head;
    while ( s != null ) 
    {
      w += s + "\n";
      s = s.getNext();
    }
    return w;
  }

  //intersection method
public String intersection(pNode head, dNode head) {
int left = posting.head;
int right = dictionary.head;
int result = new dictionary();

while (left != null && right != null) {
     if (dID.left < dID.right) {
     left = left.next;
else if (dID.left > dID.right)
     right = right.next;
else 
     left = left.next;
     right = right.next;
     result.push(left.data() );
     }
}
return result;
}  
}


public class dNode 
{
  //variables
  String sent;
  posting post;
  dNode nextNode;

  //constructor
  public dNode(String sent, posting post, dNode nextNode)
  {
    this.sent = sent;
    this.post = post;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
  }

  //returns element of this node
  public String getSent() {
    return sent;
  }

  //retunrs the next node of this node
  public dNode getNext() {
    return nextNode;
  }

  //modifier methods
  //sets elements of this node.
  public void setSent(String newSent) {
    sent = newSent;
  }

  //sets the next node of this node
  public void setNext( dNode newNext) {
    nextNode = newNext;
  }
  //toString method
  public String toString() 
  {
    return "Sentence and Posting: \n" + sent + "\n" + post;
  }
}


public class pNode {
  //variables
  int dID;
  String word;
  int occurence;
  pNode next;

  //constructor
  public pNode(int dID, String word, int occurence, pNode next)
  {
    this.dID = dID;
    this.word = word;
    this.occurence = occurence;
    this.next = next;
  }
  //return element of this node
  public String getWord() {
    return word;
  }

  //Returns the next node of this node
  public pNode getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  //Modifier methods
  //set the words of this node
  public void setWord(String newWord) {
    word = newWord;
  }

  //sets the next node of this node
  public void setNext(pNode newNext){
    next = newNext;
  }

  //toString method
  public String toString() {
    return "Document ID, Word, Occurence: \n " + dID + ", " 
      + word + ", " + occurence;
  }

}


public class posting 
{
  //variables
  pNode head;
  int size;

  //constructor
  public posting() 
  {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
  }

  //addFirst method 
  public void addFirst(pNode s) 
  {
    s.setNext(head);
    head = s;
    size++;
  }

  //addLast method
  public void addLast(pNode s)
  {
    if ( head == null )
    {
      head = s;
    }
    else
    {
      s.setNext(null);
      pNode w = head;
      while ( w.getNext() != null ) 
      {
        w = w.getNext();
      }
      w.setNext(s);
    }
    size++;
  }

  //toString method
  public String toString()
  {
    String w = "";
    pNode s = head;
    while ( s != null) 
    {
      w += s + "\n";
      s = s.getNext();
    }
    return w;
  }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

  public class testFile
  {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
  {
    File filename = new File("/export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/sentences.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(filename);
    dictionary Dictionary = new dictionary();

   while ( scan.hasNextLine() )
   {
     String sentence = scan.nextLine();
     String[] word = sentence.split(" ");

     //first element is document id
     int dID = Integer.parseInt( word[0] );

     //insertion sort
     for ( int i = 2; i < word.length; i++ )
     {
       for ( int j = i; j > 1; j-- )
       {
        if ( word[j].compareTo( word[j-1] ) > 0 )
        {
          String switchs = word[j];
          word[j] = word[j-1];
          word[j-1] = switchs;
        }
       }
     }

     //integer array count
     int[] count = new int[word.length];
     for ( int i = 1; i < word.length; i++)
     {
       for ( int j = 1; j < word.length; j++)
       {
         if (word[i].equalsIgnoreCase( word[j] ) )
         {
           count[i]++;
         }
       }
     }

     posting posts = new posting();

     for ( int i = 1; i < word.length; i++ )
     {
       if ( (i > 1 ) && (word[i].equalsIgnoreCase( word[i-1] ) ) )
         continue;
       else
       {
         posts.addFirst(new pNode(dID, word[i], count[i], null) );
       }
     }

     Dictionary.addLast(new dNode(sentence, posts, null) );
   }





   //print out output
   System.out.println(Dictionary);
  }
  }
```

This is the sentences file:

```
1 a rose is a rose 
2 John chased a cat and the cat chased John
3 cats are mammals but mammals are not cats
4 beavers build dams but i know a beaver that does not
5 my dog chased a cat and the cat attacked my dog
6 my dog likes cats but my cat dislikes dogs
7 my dog likes roses but roses dislike my dog
8 my cat dislikes roses but roses like my cat
9 red roses are not my favorite roses
10 my favorite roses are pink roses
```

If I could get some insight on how to intersect the two linked lists(or if there is anything else wrong with my program) I would really greatly appreciate it.  I have been sick for the last week and my professor refuses to help me on what I missed(apparently I am not a serious programmer if I don't come to class when I 'm sick). I really cannot stand the way this professor teaches this class because she doesn't give us any examples of the programs(and the very few she does give us always have errors). She also just gives us algorithms and she's already stated, they are not always correct.  I used to love programming but she has really turned me off on it and all I am trying to do now is get at least a C so I can just switch over to IT. I would really appreciate if someone can help me, I am desperate to just get done with this class and not have to take this professor ever again.

I adding an intersect method but am still receiving all these errors:
7 errors found:
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: illegal start of expression
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: ';' expected
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: not a statement
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: ';' expected
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: not a statement
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 86]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:86: ';' expected
File: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java  [line: 96]
Error: /export/home/hawkdom2/s0878044/CS503/assignment2/testFile.java:96: 'else' without 'if'

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void findIntersection(LLNode head1, LLnode head2)
    {
        HashSet<LLNode> hs= new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<LLNode> hs2 = new HashSet<>();
        LLNode currentNode1 = head1; 

        while(currentNode.getNext()!=null)
        {
            hs.add(currentNode);
            currentNode1 = currentNode1.getNext();
        }

        LLNode currentNode2 = head2;
        while(currentNode2.getNext()!=null)
        {  
        if(hs1.contains(currentNode2)){
             hs2.add(currentNode2);
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersecting two sorted lists is easy.

Start with a pointer to the first node in each list.  Let's call them `left` and `right`.  Create a new empty list, let's call it `result`.  Now you loop, comparing the data stored at the `left` and `right` nodes:

- If the data at `left` is less, advance `left`.
- If the data at `right` is less, advance `right`.
- If the data is equal, add it to `result` and advance both `left` and `right`.

Your loop continues until you read the end of either `left` or `right`.  Now you have intersected the two lists (*ie* the `result` list contains only the elements that appear in both `left` and `right`).

```
function intersect( list1, list2 )
    left <- list1.head
    right <- list2.head
    result <- new list

    while left != null and right != null
        if left.data < right.data
            left <- left.next
        elseif left.data > right.data
            right <- right.next
        else
            left <- left.next
            right <- right.next
            result.push(left.data)
        end if
    end

    return result
end function
```

For the best speeds, either store a `tail` pointer in your list (so that `addLast` is quick), or always add on the front (so your result is reverse-sorted) and then reverse the list afterwards (a simple operation with linear time-complexity).

Comment: Thank you so much! Would I place this in the testFile class along with the linked lists? Is my code correct so far to do the intersection?

Comment: Put it wherever it makes most sense to you.  Since you called the list `dictionary`, you might consider making it always sorted (*ie* do an ordered insert).  Then it would make sense to put the `intersect` method in `dictionary`.  Otherwise put it in the class that loads and sorts the data.  Your code doesn't look right, and that's not just because there's no `end if` in java.  Read my three steps very carefully.  If it doesn't say to advance a particular pointer, then you don't.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused on how to write the coding for it.

Comment: would it be possible to go over this again. Sorry I'm really confused  on the algorithm.

Comment: I added pseudocode to my answer to illustrate.  If you are still confused, write out two sorted lists of numbers on paper and run them through the algorithm.  You'll get it.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote out the code but it still doesn't work(I added the code and errors to my original post). should list1 and list2 be posting and dictionary for me since that is where the heads are located?

Comment: You took my pseudocode and just dumped it in with a few curly braces.  Please write *Java*.  You can do this!  I have faith.  You already wrote most of a program.  You need to declare types on your variables, and use functions that exist on your objects.  Also, logical AND is `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: I really have and I'm still a little lost. I'm confused as to what I should be calling where you wrote list1 and list2.

Comment: Those are the head nodes of the two lists you are trying to intersect.

Comment: I updated the original post with the intersection method in the dictionary class. I am hoping it is correct(fingers crossed). Only issue is I am getting the error " 'else'without 'if' " for the else if (left > right) line. I am not sure why though

Comment: Watch your curly braces.  You forgot to put them on all your if-blocks.  For single-line blocks you don't need them, but based on the difficulties you are having getting a program to compile, I would recommend you *always* use curly braces.  I get the feeling that you didn't write the rest of the code in your question.

Comment: I wrote the code, my tutor helped me with the testfile because I was unsure of how to bring the sentences.txt into the program and how to use it

Comment: Have you managed to get the new part to compile?  Perhaps you need to see your tutor again if you're still having difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

My version to find intersection of two linked list goes like below:
1. Iterate through first linked list and add element in IdentityHashMap as key.
2. Iterate through second linked list and go for containsKey check. If true then node is intersecting.

Time Complexity: O(n+m) where n = size of first list, m= size of second list
Space Complexity: O(n)